# How to execute an SSIS package from .NET Webapi with sql server authentication mode?

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, ssis

I have the following code that to execute the SSIS package from .Net Webapi, like this:

```
            string targetServerName = "1.x.x.x";
            string folderName = "MyFolder";
            string projectName = "MyProject";
            string packageName = "Package.dtsx";

            // Create a connection to the server
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=" + targetServerName +
                ";Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa; Password=abcd@1234;Persist Security Info=True;";
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

            // Create the Integration Services object
            IntegrationServices integrationServices = new IntegrationServices(sqlConnection);

            // Get the Integration Services catalog
            Catalog catalog = integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"];

            // Get the folder
            CatalogFolder folder = catalog.Folders[folderName];

            // Get the project
            ProjectInfo project = folder.Projects[projectName];

            // Get the package
            PackageInfo package = project.Packages[packageName];

            // Run the package
            package.Execute(false, null);
```

But when I run this code I get the following exception:

> *The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Windows
>   Authentication.*

What should I do so that I am able to execute the SSIS package from sql server authentication mode? Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: From [The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. SSIS Package](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198914/the-operation-cannot-be-started-by-an-account-that-uses-sql-server-authenticatio) - _"You cannot use a SQL Account to run an SSIS package in the Integration Services Catalog. There is logic within the CLR methods that are used to run the SSIS packages that reject non-windows authentication"_ - the answer to that question gives some workarounds.

Comment: The connection string you have server name and instance of server.  I do not see the instance.  A sql server database can have either a Windows Credential or a SQL Credential.  When using Windows credential you do not provide a username and password it automatically comes the the user login.  But you have a WebApi where the client only has Guest Privileges and client does not pass credentials.  
So I think you have to run service as an admin and setup database to use the admin account.  So when a client connects the web service uses the admin account.  Make the database credential the admin.

Comment: If you can start an Agent job then you can stat a job with a SSIS step in it via `sp_start_job`